# HTML table to array key issue

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I currently have a function which creates an array from a html table the array output is

```
array:1 [
  0 => array:3 [
    0 => "Test"
    1 => "Test"
    2 => "Test"
  ]
]
```

Method for creating array from HTML

```
let convertedIntoArray = [];
        $("table#campaign_csv_table tr").each(function () {
            let rowDataArray = [];
            let actualData = $(this).find('textarea');
            if (actualData.length > 0) {
                actualData.each(function () {
                    rowDataArray.push($(this).text());
                });
                convertedIntoArray.push(rowDataArray);
            }
        });
```

How would I modify this array so it looks like this:

```
array:1 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "first_name" => "Test"
    "last_name" => "Test"
    "email" => "Test"
  ]
```

**HTML table**

```
<table class="display">
    <thead>
    <tr class="header">
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
 
            <td id="table-cells"
              ><textarea rows="1" cols="50" style="resize: none" required
                                                                                  
                                                                                  ></textarea>
            </td>
            <td id="table-cells"
              ><textarea rows="1" cols="50" style="resize: none" required
                                                                                  
                                                                                  ></textarea>
            </td>
       
       
                <td id="table-cells" class="text-danger"><textarea rows="1" cols="50" style="resize: none" required
                                                                                   class="text-danger w-100"> Invalid Email Address</textarea>
                </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I've tried using array_values() within PHP but had no luck can anyone see where im going wrong?

Comment: It looks like you really want an Array of Objects rather than an Array of Arrays.  So perhaps `rowDataArray` should be `rowDataObject` and rather than pushing `$(this).text()`, you'd set the object key and value instead. But hard to tell without your HTML and where `first_name`, etc are coming from. You should include your html as well so we can attempt to recreate this.

Comment: @user1599011 I've added the HTML of the table for you

Comment: I don't think we need the php; we don't have access to all your php variables. Please use the rendered html only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to push an object instead of an array since you want string keys.

Since your input fields aren't named, I'm using my own array `let name = ...` to determine the key names based on the index number.

```
let convertedIntoArray = [];
$("table#campaign_csv_table tr").each(function () {
    let rowDataArray = {};
    let actualData = $(this).find('textarea');
    if (actualData.length > 0) {
        actualData.each(function (i) {
            let name = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email'][i]
            rowDataArray[name] = $(this).text();
        });
        convertedIntoArray.push(rowDataArray);
    }
});

console.log(convertedIntoArray)
```